# Android: how to remove checked rows in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview, checkedtextview

When I click a button I make this listener find which items are checked in order to delete them

```
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int itemCount = list.getChildCount();
            for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++){
                    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i))
                        Log.v("DELETE TEST - position ", Integer.toString(i)+ " item checked");
                    else
                        Log.v("DELETE TEST - position ", Integer.toString(i)+ " item not checked");
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
```

This is the list used in the preceding listener

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
  </ListView>
```

This is the layout used by the custom adapter with layout inflater

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

   <CheckedTextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="name"
       android:id="@+id/name"
       android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
       android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="field1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="number"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

It seems that Android load only a fixed number of cells.
If the screen space can show only N cells then childCount will return this number even if there are more of N cells in the real list.
So when I see if they are checked I get only N results, even if I scrolled the entired list and checked some other "not-showed" cell.

Example:

- cell 0
- cell 1 checked
- cell 2
- cell 3
- cell 4 checked

If N=3 and the screen shows 3 cells from 0 to 2 I get a list of false, true, false from 0 to 2 and I miss false,true from 3-4.

There must be some mistake. I'd like to do a multiplice choice deletion in listviews but this behaviour is odd. Please tell me if there is also a better way.

EDIT:
in onCreate()

```
Cursor cur = db.query(...);
adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, cur, 0);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the adapter has only a method where I populate the view inflated by its newView method with the values pointed by the Cursor.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list and only add unchecked rows. Then update the adapters's collection and notify datasetchanded

```
SparseBooleanArray newList = new SparseBooleanArray();

SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
int itemCount = list.getChildCount();
for(int i=0; i<itemCount; i++){
    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
        Log.v("DELETE TEST - position ", Integer.toString(i)+ " item checked");
    }

    else{
        Log.v("DELETE TEST - position ", Integer.toString(i)+ " item not checked");
        newList.add(checkedItemPositions.get(i));
    }
}
checkedItemPositions.clear();

theListUsedInAdapter.clear();
theListUsedInAdapter.addAll(newList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: list is ListView type and doesn't have clear() or addAll. What's the use of newList?

Comment: the problem is that I can't get all unchecked rows because getCheckeditemPositions returns checks only the visible rows in the screen size

Comment: in fact I did mistake, can you send me a code using your adapter from your activity/fragment, the newlist will only contains content to display on the listview. In my sample it's false, I'll update it when got your code

Comment: I made an update, I only use the adapter in onCreate and change it whenever I change a Cursor

Comment: Oh your using a cursor adapter, it's harder than using an array adapter for  work...

Comment: I think the problem is only in getCheckedPosition. It doesn't care if there are more cells in the listview, otherwise there wouldn't be any problem to get the list of checked rows

Comment: It was getChildCount... with getCount I get the entire list of checked position, now there is another problem because when I click a checkbox it becomes green bordered but no check mark.

Comment: I realized what the problem was; CheckedTextView must be alone, with no ViewGroups otherwise the custom layout must implement Checkable.